# sharing code in custom module

Tags: 8

I have a small module that basically contains a controller and a block plugin. I cannot figure out how to include a class in both of them

The files are located in sites/all/modules/my_module. That directory contais

```
$ ls -R  
.:
config/  my_module.info.yml       my_module.links.menu.yml  src/
css/     my_module.libraries.yml  my_module.routing.yml

./config:
install/

./config/install:
my_module.settings.yml

./css:
hello_block-layout.css

./src:
Controller/  Plugin/  Utils.php

./src/Controller:
MyController.php*

./src/Plugin:
Block/

./src/Plugin/Block:
MyBlock.php
```

The problem is the namespaces:
MyController.php has namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller and
MyBlock.php has namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block

I can use the class definition in Utils.php for one of the two, if I insert a require_once in the file (with the *whole path*, use of .. seems not to be working) AND I use the same namespace in it.

So if MyController.php starts with

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

require_once '/home/rdgon/public_html/sites/all/modules/my_module/src/Utils.php';
```

and MyBlock.php starts with

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;

require_once '/home/rdgon/public_html/sites/all/modules/my_module/src/Utils.php';
```

and Utils.php starts with

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;
```

then the class is used by correctly by the controller. But then MyBlock.php complains about not finding the class, because the namespaces don't match.

My question: is it possible to share (include) a class definition by several components of a module? What location should I use for the shared code and what is the proper way to include it? (using the full path of the file cannot be the way to go)

thanks in advance, Ruud

Comment: You never use require or require once. You use `use` statement and dependency injection. Look at core Unicode class for another example. Or define it as a service. The auto loaded will figure it all out for you.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your help. I tried using *use* instead, but I cannot get it to work. In the controller, I repaced the require_once with 'use Drupal\my_module\includes\Tester;', in Utils.php I changed the namespace in 'Drupal\my_module\includes'. The file contais the definition for class Tester. However, the error.log keeps saying 'Error: Class 'Drupal\\my_module\\Controller\\Drupal\\my_module\\includes\\Tester' not found in /...../modules/my_module/src/Controller/MyController.php on line 30. Any idea?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, I tried both running update.php and clearing the caches. I changed the namespace to Drupal\my_module, because the errorlog made clear I made another mistake. It now says 'Error: Class 'Drupal\\my_module\\Tester' not found in /..../modules/my_module/src/Controller/MyController.php on line 30'

Comment: You need to update the post with the code now because it's impossible to tell in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the class declared in `my_module/src/Utils.php` to be made available to *any* PHP script, add this at the top of that script file:

```
use Drupal\my_module\Utils;
```

This of course assumes that you're following the correct PSR-4 standards for naming: make sure that mymodule/src/Utils.php exists, and contains one single class named `Utils`, with `namespace Drupal\my_module` at the top.

See [PSR-4 namespaces and autoloading in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2156625) for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Clive for helping me on this. The problem was that I had *two* classes in Utils.php, class Utils and class Tester. Moving the Tester class to Tester.php did the trick. I can't believe I have tried this before ;)

Comment: One class per file.